# nparray unique() gives none unique array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

i have an dataframe like this:

```
      quantity  price
202     1       3.99
287     1       3.99
309     1       3.99
1345    3       11.97
1681    1       14.36
... ... ...
275754  1       3.59
275922  1       3.99
275927  1       3.99
276012  1       3.99
276065  1       3.59
```

And i need unique itemprices:

```
df['item_price'] = (df['price'] / df['quantity'])
```

but

```
df.item_price.unique()
```

gives this: (note the 3.99)

```
[ 3.99,  0.  ,  3.99,  3.59, 14.36]
```

i have tried many solutions (`strip()`,`str.replace(' ', '')`, `return_index=False`, `return_inverse=False`, `return_counts=False` ... and so on),
But without luck.
3.99 is always doubled.
Whats wrong with that?

Comment: You should round the numbers before making them unique, because they probably have differences in some low-order fraction digits that aren't shown by default. Floating point has inherent inaccuracies like this.

Comment: Try: `df['item_price'].round(2).unique()`

Comment: @mozway gives the simplest solution for my current problem. I hate floats.

Comment: @IngoEyring you may have an easier time if you redefine the units to be integers, even if this means a little upfront pain thinking about, say transactions in micro-Euros